# Slice chunking in Go

Tags: go, slice, chunking

I have a slice with ~2.1 million log strings in it, and I would like to create a slice of slices with the strings being as evenly distributed as possible.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// logs is a slice with ~2.1 million strings in it.
var divided = make([][]string, 0)
NumCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
ChunkSize := len(logs) / NumCPU
for i := 0; i < NumCPU; i++ {
    temp := make([]string, 0)
    idx := i * ChunkSize
    end := i * ChunkSize + ChunkSize
    for x := range logs[idx:end] {
        temp = append(temp, logs[x])
    }
    if i == NumCPU {
        for x := range logs[idx:] {
            temp = append(temp, logs[x])
        }
    }
    divided = append(divided, temp)
}
```

The `idx := i * ChunkSize` will give me the current "chunk start" for the `logs` index, and `end := i * ChunkSize + ChunkSize` will give me the "chunk end", or the end of the range of that chunk. I couldn't find any documentation or examples on how to chunk/split a slice or iterate over a limited range in Go, so this is what I came up with. However, it only copies the first chunk multiple times, so it doesn't work.

How do I (as evenly as possible) chunk an slice in Go?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You don't need to make new slices, just append slices of `logs` to the `divided` slice.

http://play.golang.org/p/vyihJZlDVy

```
var divided [][]string

chunkSize := (len(logs) + numCPU - 1) / numCPU

for i := 0; i < len(logs); i += chunkSize {
    end := i + chunkSize

    if end > len(logs) {
        end = len(logs)
    }

    divided = append(divided, logs[i:end])
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", divided)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh that's what I was missing. I kept trying to iterate over a limited range instead of iterating via chunk length. I spent 8 hours trying to figure out how to get mine working, lol. Thanks for the answer, super helpful.

Comment: You look to be off by one in the length of `divided`. For example, `numCPU = 3; logs = logs[:8]; chunkSize := len(logs) / numCPU; if chunkSize == 0 { chunkSize = 1 };` divides into 4, not 3, for 3 cpus and 8 logs: http://play.golang.org/p/EdhiclVR0q. For `chunkSize`, write `chunkSize := (len(logs) + numCPU - 1) / numCPU;`: http://play.golang.org/p/xDyFXt45Fz.

Comment: @peterSO: thanks, just copied that from the original and didn't think to check.

Comment: If anyone's wondering what `(len(logs) + numCPU - 1) / numCPU` is, it's simply the ceil of `len(logs)/numCPU`

Answer (score 18):

Using generics (Go version >=1.18):

```
func chunkBy[T any](items []T, chunkSize int) (chunks [][]T) {
    for chunkSize < len(items) {
        items, chunks = items[chunkSize:], append(chunks, items[0:chunkSize:chunkSize])
    }
    return append(chunks, items)
}
```

[Playground URL](https://go.dev/play/p/waOZybU74L5)

Or if you want to manually set the capacity:

```
func chunkBy[T any](items []T, chunkSize int) [][]T {
    var _chunks = make([][]T, 0, (len(items)/chunkSize)+1)
    for chunkSize < len(items) {
        items, _chunks = items[chunkSize:], append(_chunks, items[0:chunkSize:chunkSize])
    }
    return append(_chunks, items)
}
```

[Playground URL](https://go.dev/play/p/S0ZW8I7h-Lt)

Comment: Best one!
But return value could be improved for e.g. ```items := var s []int```. I can update, shall I?

Answer (score 7):

Per [Slice Tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#batching-with-minimal-allocation)

Batching with minimal allocation

> **Useful if you want to do batch processing on large slices.**

```golang
actions := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
batchSize := 3
batches := make([][]int, 0, (len(actions) + batchSize - 1) / batchSize)

for batchSize < len(actions) {
    actions, batches = actions[batchSize:], append(batches, actions[0:batchSize:batchSize])
}
batches = append(batches, actions)
```

Yields the following:

```
[[0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8] [9]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another variant. It works about 2.5 times faster than the one proposed by [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb). The tests and benchmarks are [here](https://github.com/bcmk/chunks-benchmarks).

https://play.golang.org/p/WoXHqGjozMI

```
func chunks(xs []string, chunkSize int) [][]string {
    if len(xs) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    divided := make([][]string, (len(xs)+chunkSize-1)/chunkSize)
    prev := 0
    i := 0
    till := len(xs) - chunkSize
    for prev < till {
        next := prev + chunkSize
        divided[i] = xs[prev:next]
        prev = next
        i++
    }
    divided[i] = xs[prev:]
    return divided
}
```

Comment: `It works about 2.5 times faster` this is unexplained, unfortunately. My guess is, less JT allocations.

Comment: @mh-cbon The main reason is the preallocated slice as we know its exact final size. It gives us 9 allocs/op instead of 53 and most of the speed gain

Comment: Also works for `chunkSize > len(xs)`

Answer (score 1):

```
func chunkSlice(items []int32, chunkSize int32) (chunks [][]int32) {
 //While there are more items remaining than chunkSize...
 for chunkSize < int32(len(items)) {
    //We take a slice of size chunkSize from the items array and append it to the new array
    chunks = append(chunks, items[0:chunkSize])
    //Then we remove those elements from the items array
    items = items[chunkSize:]
 }
 //Finally we append the remaining items to the new array and return it
 return append(chunks, items)
}
```

---

### Visual example

Say we want to split an array into chunks of 3

```
items:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
chunks: []

items:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
chunks: [[1,2,3]]

items:  [4,5,6,7]
chunks: [[1,2,3]]

items:  [4,5,6,7]
chunks: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

items:  [7]
chunks: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

items:  [7]
chunks: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]
return
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

use reflect for any []T

https://github.com/kirito41dd/xslice

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kirito41dd/xslice"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    i := xslice.SplitToChunks(s, 3)
    ss := i.([][]int)
    fmt.Println(ss) // [[0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8] [9]]
}
```

https://github.com/kirito41dd/xslice/blob/e50d91fa75241a3a03d262ad51c8e4cb2ea4b995/split.go#L12

```golang
func SplitToChunks(slice interface{}, chunkSize int) interface{} {
    sliceType := reflect.TypeOf(slice)
    sliceVal := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    length := sliceVal.Len()
    if sliceType.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("parameter must be []T")
    }
    n := 0
    if length%chunkSize > 0 {
        n = 1
    }
    SST := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(sliceType), 0, length/chunkSize+n)
    st, ed := 0, 0
    for st < length {
        ed = st + chunkSize
        if ed > length {
            ed = length
        }
        SST = reflect.Append(SST, sliceVal.Slice(st, ed))
        st = ed
    }
    return SST.Interface()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarize:

```golang
// ChunkStringSlice divides []string into chunks of chunkSize.
func ChunkStringSlice(s []string, chunkSize int) [][]string {
    chunkNum := int(math.Ceil(float64(len(s)) / float64(chunkSize)))
    res := make([][]string, 0, chunkNum)
    for i := 0; i < chunkNum-1; i++ {
        res = append(res, s[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    }
    res = append(res, s[(chunkNum-1)*chunkSize:])
    return res
}

// ChunkStringSlice2 divides []string into chunkNum chunks.
func ChunkStringSlice2(s []string, chunkNum int) [][]string {
    res := make([][]string, 0, chunkNum)
    chunkSize := int(math.Ceil(float64(len(s)) / float64(chunkNum)))
    for i := 0; i < chunkNum-1; i++ {
        res = append(res, s[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    }
    res = append(res, s[(chunkNum-1)*chunkSize:])
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [go-deeper/chunks](https://github.com/go-deeper/chunks) module that allows to split a slice of any type (with generics) into chunks with approximately equals sum of values.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-deeper/chunks"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    sliceChunks := chunks.Split(slice, 7)

    fmt.Println(sliceChunks)
}
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5] [6 7 8 9 10]]
```